# How to display a search result in a treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, treeview, razorengine

Currently, I'm working in a MVC project (this is my first project). I'm doing fine but I'm stuck somewhere. I hope someone will help me out with this.

In this project I have to search for a record (with id) in SQL database from visual studio, where I should get result in a treeview... like under ID we may have a lot of sub ids or may not, if we have one sub id, it should display one if we have multiple sub ids multi-level treeview should display.

Note: This result I should get from the database when the user searched for particular id only, DATA from the database should not be loaded with the page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tree view using css and html. Populate the value using a rest controller or controller.
create an arraylist which returns your search result.
return the value from the list to a model or a url using a function.
As you can see there are many ways you can do this.

you can check this out as well: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/85ed7a/searching-records-from-database-and-display-in-gridview-and/

and for only loading id from the database you can run

```
Select id From tablename
```

and if you want the details only after user clicks the id

```
Select * From tablename Where id = clickedvalue
```

you could also use where statement in sql to have more specific values
you'll need to change few codes as this tutorial uses grid view.
i hope this helps. But please provide some code snippets of what you've done or where you're stuck to get a precise answer.